# Good Looking GUI For Twitter Client In Java

Tags: java, user-interface, twitter

how we can develop a twitter client (for desktop) in java like [Seesmic](http://seesmic.com/products/desktop) , i know to deal with twitter api using twitter4j but, how to develop user interface like Seesmic? 
what are the java technologies i should use? , i guess that i can't do the same using swing.

any help please.thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally have not used it, but there is a fair amount of buzz around [javafx](http://javafx.com/). [(tutorials here)](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/tutorials.html)

Answer (score 2):

You would be surprised by the things you can achieve with Swing reading this book: http://filthyrichclients.org :-). Anyway, I think a good choose would be JavaFX as Ransom Briggs suggests, as it is supposed to be a "replacement" for Swing in java desktop applications. Other good options you could evaluate are [Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org) and [griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org) (grails-style framework for desktop applications). Griffon can run on [different UI toolkits](http://www.springone2gx.com/blog/andres_almiray/2010/01/griffon_toolkit_diversity_examples) through [plugins](http://griffon.codehaus.org/Plugins) (Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Pivot, GTK).